What is the replacement for GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount when migrating to Credential Manager API/ Authorization API?
GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount is deprecated.
May I know, what is the alternative when migrating to Credential Manager API / Authorization API?
Currently, I do not use Credential Manager API.
I am using Authorization API to perform client login based on code snippet - https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android
List<Scopes> requestedScopes = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA);
AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.builder().setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes).build();
Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this)
        .authorize(authorizationRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener(
            authorizationResult -> {
              if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                    // Access needs to be granted by the user
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = authorizationResult.getPendingIntent();
                try {
                    // This code will enable user to perform login.
                    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
REQUEST_AUTHORIZE, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start Authorization UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
              } else {
            // Access already granted, continue with user action
                saveToDriveAppFolder(authorizationResult);
              }
            })
        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e(TAG, "Failed to authorize", e));

How I can get the last login account information?

I have tried the following code snippet from AI. But, it is not what I want. The following code snippet, will prompt a login dialog. What I want to do, is silently retrieve the last login account I use to access Google Drive.

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.credentials.CredentialManager;
import androidx.credentials.CredentialManagerCallback;
import androidx.credentials.GetCredentialRequest;
import androidx.credentials.GetCredentialResponse;
import androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialException;
import com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid.GetGoogleIdOption;
import com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid.GoogleIdTokenCredential;

public class AuthManager {
    private final Context context;
    private final CredentialManager credentialManager;

    public AuthManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context);
    }

    public interface AuthCallback {
        void onSuccess(GoogleIdTokenCredential credential);
        void onFailure(Exception e);
    }

    public void getLastSignedInAccount(AuthCallback callback) {
        GetGoogleIdOption googleIdOption = new GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                .setServerClientId(WENOTE_CLOUD_STORAGE_CLIENT_ID)
                .build();

        GetCredentialRequest request = new GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                .build();

        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "Call getCredentialAsync");

        credentialManager.getCredentialAsync(
                context,
                request,
                null,   // pass in a CancelationSignal to allow cancelling the request
                Runnable::run,          // Execute the callback immediately
                new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull GetCredentialResponse result) {
                        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onResult " + result);

                        if (result != null) {
                            GoogleIdTokenCredential credential = (GoogleIdTokenCredential) result.getCredential();
                            callback.onSuccess(credential);
                        } else {
                            callback.onFailure(new Exception("No credential found"));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull GetCredentialException e) {
                        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onError " + e);

                        // Handle errors
                        callback.onFailure(e);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}


Using Identity.getAuthorizationClient
Another approach I have been trying is using Identity.getAuthorizationClient. But, it is giving me null all-time-time.
private void xxx() {
    Log.i("CHEOK", "xxx");

    List<Scope> requestedScopes = Arrays.asList(
            new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA),
            new Scope("email"),
            new Scope("profile"),
            new Scope("openid")
    );

    AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.builder()
            .setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes)
            .build();

    Identity.getAuthorizationClient(getContext())
            .authorize(authorizationRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(authorizationResult -> {
                if (!authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                    // No user intervention required, we have the user details
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = authorizationResult.toGoogleSignInAccount();
                    Log.i("CHEOK", "Email = " + account.getEmail());
                    Log.i("CHEOK", "getDisplayName = " + account.getDisplayName());
                    Log.i("CHEOK", "getId = " + account.getId());
                    Log.i("CHEOK", "getIdToken = " + account.getIdToken());
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("CHEOK", "Failed to authorize", e));
}


There is no replacement for that API in the Identity or CredentialManager worlds. Here is what I suggest you do:

When user opens your app, call CredentialManager and make a request including setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true) and setAutoSelectEnabled(true).
You either get a "NoCredentialFoundException" or you get a positive response. If you get a positive response, you can retrieve an ID Token from the response that has the email, name and profile picture of the user.
If you get a NoCredentialFoundException, it means user has not yet signed into your app, so call the same API but with setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false) which shows a bottomsheet to the user with all accounts listed so your user can select an account and sign up/in to your app. You will get an ID Token that has the above information.
Later on in your app, when user reaches a point that a Drive access is needed by your app, call the Authorization APIs and only ask for Drive access. Since your user is already signed in, they are not going to see an account selector. If they have previously given consent to access their Drive, you immediately get back a response that has an AccessToken. If they haven't given consent, they see a consent page and if they accept, you get an AccessToken.

Now let's see how this works: if a user is new, following the above flow results in seeing the bottomsheet, user selects an account and you get an ID Token that has the user information (so you take a note of that), they go in and at the right moment, you prompt them for Drive access, they accept the consent and you get an AccessToken. So all is good for that flow. Now, the next time the user opens your app, you do the same as above but this time, since the user had previously signed into your app, they will not be prompted with the bottomsheet as before; instead they see a bottomsheet that only shows up for a second or two, telling the user that he/she is being signed in (and requires no interaction from the user) and disappears on its own and you will get an ID Token which has the user info (which you will take a note of it) and again when you reach the appropriate moment, you call, as outlined above, the Authorization APIs but this time you get an AccessToken immediately (with no user interaction required) and you are good to go.
Does this flow give you what you want?

Thank you. I have 2 questions. My 1st question is, calling credentialManager.getCredentialAsync will always prompt the UI, even this user is already "sign in". Is there a way to do it silently, without showing the UI? This is the video showing what happens when credentialManager.getCredentialAsync is called multiple times : https://imgur.com/a/n5Q6e60 . This is the triggered function https://gist.github.com/yccheok/d2f16a7807ee6cf73347153a4a8ebb53

My 2nd question is, to avoid making the multiple flows complication, can we only use ONLY Authorization API to sign in user + Google Drive service access? We will only use CredentialManager to retrieve last login account info.

Regarding your first question, that UI is not avoidable; it is the U that I had referred to in my original response: a transient UI that disappears after 2 seconds or so. It is there to show the user that he/she is being signed in. On the second question, "authentication/sign-in" is usually associated with getting an ID Token. The Authorization APIs do not return an ID Token. You can, if needed, call the Authorization APIs and ask for profile+email+openid scopes, in addition to the drive scope, and then use the access token you've receive to call the people-api service ... continued

... to obtain the user information, if that is all you need. On a different note, when a user opens your app, you should call the CredentialManager APIs to authenticate the user; then, except for the first time, that will result in that transient UI and IMHO, that is a good thing for the user to see that transient UI; it is a signal to them that they are now signed-in as that user (that transient UI shows the user info). In fact, if you call the same API but directly using the OneTap APIs, that transient UI also has a "cancel" button for the user to stop the auto sign-in process ... continued

... but that "cancel" button is not there if you use the CredentialManager APIs; the reason is due to the interactions between the CredentialManager and the OneTap APIs which handles the request behind the scene which I am hoping to address soon.

Use this code after you have logged in using Credential Manager API
To integrate the Credential Manager API with Google Drive access, you can implement a function to handle the authorization and use the resulting AuthorizationResult to create a Google Drive service. Here's how you can do it:
Step 1: Check if the User is Logged In
This function checks whether the user is authorized with the required Google Drive scopes and handles the AuthorizationResult:
fun isGoogleLoggedIn(callback: (Boolean,AuthorizationResult?) -> Unit){
    val requestedScopes: List<Scope> = listOf(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA))
    val authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.builder().setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes).build()

    Identity.getAuthorizationClient(context)
        .authorize(authorizationRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener { authorizationResult ->
            if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                //we can ask for login!
                appSettings.isGoogleDriveAuthorized = false
                callback.invoke(false,authorizationResult)
            } else {
                // Access already granted, continue with user action
                appSettings.isGoogleDriveAuthorized = true
                callback.invoke(true,authorizationResult)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            e.printStackTrace()
            showErrorLog("Failed to authorize")
            callback.invoke(false,null)
        }
}

private fun getDriveService(callback: (Drive?) -> Unit) {
    isGoogleLoggedIn {
        result,authorizationResult ->

        if(authorizationResult == null || authorizationResult.hasResolution() || !appSettings.isGoogleDriveAuthorized){
            showLog("Account authorization failed!!")
            callback.invoke(null)
            return@isGoogleLoggedIn
        }

        ensureBackgroundThread {
            if(result){

                val accessToken = authorizationResult.accessToken
                showLog("Granted Scopes - ${authorizationResult.grantedScopes}")
                val credential = GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(NetHttpTransport())
                    .setJsonFactory(GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                    .build()
                    .setAccessToken(accessToken)

                callback.invoke(Drive.Builder(
                    NetHttpTransport(),
                    GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                    credential).setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build())
            } else {
                callback.invoke(null)
            }
        }
    }
}

New User Authorization
If your user is newly signing in then they need to authorize drive access just once and then you will be able to do drive access without any extra dialogs or permissions.
private val requestAuthorizeLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data = result.data
            if (data != null) {
                val authorizationResult = Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this).getAuthorizationResultFromIntent(data)
                if(authorizationResult.hasResolution()){
                   showToast(getString(R.string.please_allow_the_permission_for_google_drive_backup))
                } else {
                    settings.isGoogleDriveAuthorized = true
                    refreshInfo()
                }
            }
        } else {
            showToast(getString(R.string.please_allow_the_permission_for_google_drive_backup))
        }
    }

private fun authorizeDrive(){
    googleDriveHelper.isGoogleLoggedIn { result, authorizationResult ->
        hideProgressBar()
        if(result){
            refreshInfo()
         
        } else {
            if(authorizationResult!=null && authorizationResult.pendingIntent != null){

                try {
                    val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(authorizationResult.pendingIntent!!.intentSender).build()
                    requestAuthorizeLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest)
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.couldn_t_start_authorization_try_again))
                }

            } else {
                showToast(getString(R.string.try_again))
            }
        }
    }
}

Here settings.isGoogleDriveAuthorized = true this is only to set a flag offline in shared pref. so i can show a button to user 'Enable Backup' which will show a authorization dialog only if required.
So now the final flow is
User taps sign in with google button in your app > you call sign in code where credential manager is implemented > after the success result > you call authorizeDrive() function > now it checks if the app is already authorized or not, if it is you can just refresh any info you are show or else it will show a dialog using pending intent to authorize drive > this will do two things at the same time 1st authenticate using credential manager api and then authroize the app to use google drive as well.
Using this approach, you should be able to back up data to Google Drive without interrupting the user flow. Let me know if this works for you!
